# trying to only show text that is not wrapped

Tags: css

I have a image and some text which sits inside the image. My problem is when the text is wrapped because of the length I down want is displayed.

```
.temp-image .list .list.caption {  
  background-image:url(bar.png);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  left: 1px;
  line-height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  top: 190px;
  width: 256px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the css

```
.temp-image .list .list.caption {  
  background-image:url(bar.png);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  left: 1px;
  line-height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  top: 190px;
  width: 256px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevents Wrapping */
  }
```

Comment: @Wantingtolearn Thanks, I knew there was a dash in there somewhere, I put it on nowrap originally.